# Pandas - Delete old NA rows with new data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I have a DataFrame:

```
df
    shelf   jar_lid_color  jar_material  jar_owner  size
0   1       red            glass         David      20
1   1       NaN            glass         Bob        12
2   2       blue           plastic       NaN        7
3   2       green          NaN           Julia      19
4   1       pink           plastic       Peter      9
```

And someone adds a row via a UI:

```
newdata
    shelf   jar_lid_color  jar_material  jar_owner  size
0   2       blue           plastic       Oscar      7
```

Resulting in:

```
df_new
    shelf   jar_lid_color  jar_material  jar_owner  size
0   1       red            glass         David      20
1   1       NaN            glass         Bob        12
2   2       blue           plastic       NaN        7
3   2       green          NaN           Julia      19
4   1       pink           plastic       Peter      9
5   2       blue           plastic       Oscar      7
```

- The program doesn't have any logic to know if the data added is new data or has to replace old data with missing values
- The user using the UI also doesn't know if the data being introduced is already in the database
- NaN values can be in any column, which means that `drop_duplicates(subset=)` cannot be used

In this case, the data added needs to replace an old row with incomplete data, resulting in:

```
df_new
    shelf   jar_lid_color  jar_material  jar_owner  size
0   1       red            glass         David      20
1   1       NaN            glass         Bob        12
2   2       blue           plastic       Oscar      7
3   2       green          NaN           Julia      19
4   1       pink           plastic       Peter      9
```

I could always iterate over all the rows from the old database and the new added data to check if they are the same, ignoring columns where data has NaN, but this is inefficient for large DataFrames:

```
df = df.append(newdata, axis=0)
for index1, row1 in newdata.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in df.iterrows():
        cols = row2.index[~row2.isna()].tolist()
        if row1.loc[cols].equals(row2.loc[cols]):
            df.loc[index2] = row1
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: As I said, I could iterate over both DataFrame rows to check each line, ignoring the first one's NaN columns for each row. Sorry if I made myself unclear, I added a code example, hopefully it makes it more understandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, given the two following dataframes:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "shelf": {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 1},
        "jar_lid_color": {0: "red", 1: pd.NA, 2: "blue", 3: "green", 4: "pink"},
        "jar_material": {0: "glass", 1: "glass", 2: "plastic", 3: pd.NA, 4: "plastic"},
        "jar_owner": {0: "David", 1: "Bob", 2: pd.NA, 3: "Julia", 4: "Peter"},
        "size": {0: 20, 1: 12, 2: 7, 3: 19, 4: 9},
    }
)

new_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "shelf": {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 2},
        "jar_lid_color": {0: "blue", 1: "yellow", 2: "green"},
        "jar_material": {0: "plastic", 1: "glass", 2: "iron"},
        "jar_owner": {0: "Oscar", 1: "Bob", 2: "Julia"},
        "size": {0: 7, 1: 12, 2: 19},
    }
)
```

Your code, provided some minor bux fixes, outputs the expected result after **0.012 second in average**:

```py
import statistics
import time

def two_iterations(df, new_data):
    df = df.append(new_data).reset_index(drop=True)
    for _, row1 in new_data.iterrows():
        for index2, row2 in df.iterrows():
            cols = row2.index[~row2.isna()].tolist()
            if row1.loc[cols].equals(row2.loc[cols]):
                df.loc[index2] = row1.values
    df = df.drop_duplicates(keep="first")
    return df

elapsed_time = []
for i in range(500):
    start_time = time.time()
    new_df = two_iterations(df, new_data)
    elapsed_time.append(time.time() - start_time)
print(f"--- {statistics.mean(elapsed_time):2f} seconds in average ---")
print(new_df)

# Output
--- 0.012458 seconds in average ---
   shelf jar_lid_color jar_material jar_owner  size
0      1           red        glass     David    20
1      1        yellow        glass       Bob    12
2      2          blue      plastic     Oscar     7
3      2         green         iron     Julia    19
4      1          pink      plastic     Peter     9
```

Whereas you can skip one iteration by appending all values first and then look for duplicates in a more idiomatic way, which provides the **same result 4 times faster** (0.003 second in average):

```py
def faster_way(df, new_data):
    df = df.append(new_data).reset_index(drop=True)
    temp_df = df.copy()
    for i, row in temp_df.iterrows():
        if row.isna().sum():
            row = row.dropna()
            if any(df.loc[~df.index.isin([i]), row.index.tolist()] == row.tolist()):
                df = df.drop(index=i)
    return df

elapsed_time = []
for i in range(500):
    start_time = time.time()
    new_df = faster_way(df, new_data)
    elapsed_time.append(time.time() - start_time)
print(f"--- {statistics.mean(elapsed_time):2f} seconds in average ---")
print(new_df)

# Output
--- 0.003489 seconds in average ---
   shelf jar_lid_color jar_material jar_owner  size
0      1           red        glass     David    20
4      1          pink      plastic     Peter     9
5      2          blue      plastic     Oscar     7
6      1        yellow        glass       Bob    12
7      2         green         iron     Julia    19
```